# Why does the symbol have an arrow?

Tags: soft-question, electric-circuits, notation, electronics, electrical-engineering

What does the arrow in the symbol mean?

[image: circuit]

Does it mean that it is a variable voltmeter and ammeter?

Comment: Would [electronics.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because because it belongs on electrical engineering.

Answer (score 3):

It just shows that the item is a meter.  The arrow represents the indicator on analog meters.

Comment: See for example [this](http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/514GD8L3xNL._SY300_.jpg)

Comment: It does seem like an unfortunate and confusing symbol-space collision. For some elements, a diagonal arrow strikethrough means that the primary measure of the element is variable, for example [this](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Variable_resistor_symbol.svg). Anyone know what the historical reason is for this multiplicity of meaning?

Comment: I can't recall ever seeing that symbol for a meter. But evidently it's available as standard equipment in the Tikz circuittikz library.

Comment: All these gadgets, voltmeter, ampermeter, and potentiometer, have the symbol with the same diagonal arrow (aside from other symbols without it) because all these gadgets contain the very same thing: a component that is mechanically moving, a little hand that may point to different directions (therefore symbolized by the arrow). This is no mistake or a "collision" in notation. It's like saying that $\vec E$ and $\vec B$ are in collision because both letters have arrows above them. But that is how things should be - both quantities are vectors and that's what the arrow means in this context.

Comment: @LubošMotl Yes, but there are different standards and conventions, and in my experience (everyone's experience will be different) a diagonal arrow means *user variable*, as in a variable resistor.

Comment: Well, a kid may play with the hand on the voltmeter or ampermeter, too, can't she? ;-) The position of the hand will be a variable dictated by the user which decides about some physical consequences - e.g. about whether or not a gadget gets broken. I think that your interpretation of the arrow as a "user variable" is a self-inflicted injury. You just decide about a prejudce that the arrow can't mean the hand on a voltmeter, so then it can't mean the hand on the voltmeter. But if you "define" the arrow to represent any mechanically movable part, which is common sense, you will have no problem.